# Is there a way to extract elevation data from Google Earth?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, elevation

I'm searching for a way to get "elevation" data from Google Earth maps in a file and then to do level curves.

Do you know one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use google map API for it. Find documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/elevation/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do a lot of worldwide elevation, you can get data from the US Geological Service [here.](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GTOPO30) There are also US specific elevation products on that site if you don't need the entire globe.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this Youtube video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isDop9WKdjk&ab_channel=GeoDeltaLabs

This is an example.

What you need to do:

1. Create line in Google Earth
2. Draw this line by leaving as many points as you can at the certain lcation (as shown in the video above).
3. Save your path as the .kml file when done
4. Load yourfile to tis website:  https://www.gpsvisualizer.com/elevation
5. Click Convert & Add Elevation
6. Download .gpx file

You will receive the elevation assigned in the   tags.